# Creature Sound Design - Griffin

Tags: creature-vocalizations, fantasy, sound-design

Working on some creature sound design for a griffin - head of a bird, body of a lion.  Just trying to capture the sound of its growl/roar.  Trying to come up with something growly and menacing like a lion but it needs to sound like it's coming from a beak and should therefore sound quite different from a real lion.  Any suggestions?  I'm coming up blank.  Also wishing I had Kyma so I could use the Tau editor for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also sometimes will use Pro Tools AIR Talkbox to help shape formants of separate sounds similarly as with IR at times, usually on an aux. Its just easy to manipulate formants with it.

Answer (score 4):

We have a pretty intrinsic understanding that vocal sounds are produced from the upper half of most creatures - lungs, larynx, throat and that the size and shape of these physically affect the sound. I think it might be difficult to connect the sound and image together with the sound being predominantly from a lion. Maybe try starting with some bird sounds like Eagle screeches and see if it gels better? That's not to say that you can't put some lion in there somewhere, but perhaps it will combine better in the lower registers. You can also try pitch shifting them into similar frequency ranges and vocoding them together. Another trick is to use a bit of IR reverb to glue the sounds together - you can use impulses of very small spaces to model the creatures throat. Sometimes I use two together, one with a heavy lowpass filter to cover the sounds emanating from the body of the creature and one clean for the sound from it's mouth... or whatever it's got!